# Why recyclerview items doesn't show until scroll between tabs?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I have app that recive input from activity and needs to display it in recyclerview that imlement in tabs.
After the button pressed in the activity the values doesn't show in the target tab that I need (the 2nd one) and it shows there only after I scroll the last tab (4t) and return to the 2nd one.

Here is the code :

tab2

```
public class Tab2Fragment extends Fragment {


    private ArrayList<exampleItem> mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private exampleAdapter mAdapter = new exampleAdapter(mExampleList);
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview2);

        buildRecyclerView(v);
        loadData();

        return v;
    }
    public void removeItem(int position) {
        mExampleList.remove(position);
        //mExampleList.clear();
        //mRecyclerView.removeViewAt(position);
        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public void changeItem(int position, String text) {
        mExampleList.get(position).changeText1(text);
        mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
        private void loadData() {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("shared preferences12", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = sharedPreferences.getString("task list12", null);
            Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<exampleItem>>() {
            }.getType();
            mExampleList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
            if (mExampleList == null) {
                mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
            }
        }
        private void buildRecyclerView(View view) {
            mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview2);
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
            mAdapter = new exampleAdapter(mExampleList);
            //mRecyclerView.swapAdapter(mAdapter,false);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new exampleAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(int position) {
                    changeItem(position, "Clicked");
                }

                @Override
                public void onDeleteClickListener(int position) {
                    removeItem(position);
                }
            });
        }

}
```

mainActivty

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TabAdapter adapter;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        adapter = new TabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab1Fragment(), "main");
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab2Fragment(), "daily");
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab3Fragment(), "weekly");
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab4Fragment(), "monthly");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use notifyDataSetChanged() in changeItem and removeitem and buildRecyclerView functions.buildRecyclerView function is called before loadData and changeItem is called in onItemClick that I don't know is the same as the button you mention that you pressed. but in loadData function, you don't call notifyDataSetChanged() or other notify functions. probably this is the cause of your problem. please check that after every change in data list of recyclerview, notifyDataSetChanged() or other notify functions must is called